# Color Scaling in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to scale the color components of a pixel. To do this I am creating a new pixel where each color component is the original value * the scaling factor for that color. The resulting pixel must have values that fall within the range of `0 <= color <= 255`.

This is what I am doing so far

```
public class ColorScale implements Transformer {
    /* This part creates a transformer that scales the color in each pixel by the following factors
        parameter r0 = red factor
        parameter b0 = blue factor
        parameter g0 = green factor 
    */

    public ColorScale(double r0, double g0, double b0) {
       // need guidance as what to do here
    }

    public Pixel transformPixel(pixel p) {
        return p;
    }
}
```

More info is here: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis120/current/hw/hw07/javadoc/ColorScale.html

I am new to Java, so I just need guidance as to what to do in the ColorScale function.

Comment: I think that is the point of the homework. You need to figure out how to get the red/blue/green values from the given Pixel. Then you multiply each value by its factor. Then you have to create a new Pixel object with these values and return the Pixel from your method.

Comment: so basically I leave transformPixel as is? I only need to modify ColorScale, right?

Comment: No. transformPixel() is where you do all the calculations to transform the pixel from one color to another based on the 3 factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the JavaDoc you provided, `ColorScale` is one of the `Transformer` implementations.

From your code snippet:

```
public ColorScale(double r0, double g0, double b0) {
   // need guidance as what to do here
}
```

This is the constructor.  You are creating an `instance` of a specific implementation of a Pixel `Transformer` (in this case, `ColorScale`).

The constructor should simply set the internal state of the `Transformer`, and then it will be set up for transforming Pixels via the contract method `transformPixel`.

In other words,

```
public ColorScale(double r0, double g0, double b0) {
   // Set internal state fields. 
   this.r0 = r0;
   this.g0 = g0;
   this.b0 = b0;
}
```